# Storing multiple data entries into a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my program I have to prompt the user to enter customer info.
The information includes `first name`, `last name`, `phone number`, and `grocery items` (separate each array by a comma).

The prompt keeps asking user for info until user presses cancel or enters nothing.
ex:

```
peter,pho,123-324-2333, beans,carots,cereal
karen,smite,122-333-1223, milk,pudding
```

Each time the user enters input, I need to create an object to store the info, and each object needs a property grocery item. So I assume it goes something like this.

```
cust = prompt("enter customer info");
while(cust != null){
    var array1 = cust.split(',');
    var customer = {
       custinfo:array1.slice(0,3),
       items:array1.slice(3,array1.length)
    } 
    cust = prompt("enter");
}
```

This works for the first customer, but how do I store many entries, I don't know how much customers the user will enter. I tried creating an array of objects, if that makes any sense , like `customer[]`, but it didn't work.I split them into arrays for later use in my homework. Also how do I make the prompt run until user enters nothing?

Comment: *"I tried creating an array of objects, if that makes any sense , like customer[], but it didn't work."* Please show us what you tried. You should not have any problems with using an array after [**reading a JavaScript tutorial about arrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ordered list of items, use an [***Array***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can combine this with a `for` loop. Here is an example

```
function ask_questions(questions) {
    var answers = [],
        i,
        ans;
    for (i = 0; i < questions.length; ++i) { // for infinite loop, `while (true) {`
        ans = prompt(questions[i] || 'enter'); // default question
        if (!ans) break; // cancel or blank ends questioning
        answers[i] = ans; // do what you want with the data given
    }
    return answers;
}
```

The *function* `ask_questions` takes an *Array* (say `arr`) and `prompts` the user `arr.length` times, then returns the results of the `prompt`s as another *Array*

```
var qs = ['enter customer info', null, 'enter2']; // null will cause message "enter"
qs.length = 4; // undefined will cause message "enter"

ask_questions(qs); // ["foo", "bar", "baz", "fizz"]
```

---

However, is this really the best data structure for you? You may do better with an *Object* which has useful property names rather than indices and ask them for specific pieces of data such as their name and address rather than leaving it up to them. If you leave it all up to them you could end up with their pet's life story and their favourite colour etc or even nothing at all.

Finally, `prompt` isn't a good *UX*, use `<input>` or `<textarea>`s in your final revision